# Boost asio reading from the streambuffer after async_read_until stripes spaces

Tags: c++, boost, io, boost-asio

So after I use `async_read_until` to read until a delimiter there is some extra data that is left in the buffer and I have been trying to read it like this

```
void Connection::read_left_over(std::string &req, size_t &bytes) {
  std::istream_iterator<char> itr(this->input_stream);
  std::cout << buffer_.in_avail() << std::endl; // returns the size of the data with spaces
  bytes -= size_t(buffer_.in_avail());
  req.append(itr, std::istream_iterator<char>());
  std::cout << buffer_.in_avail() << std::endl; // returns 0
  std::cout << req << std::endl;
}
```

But the issue is the text that is been read is stripped of spaces, although before reading the buffer says it has a data with spaces and after the read it returns 0. Is there any reason to why this happening and if so a way to overcome this?

Comment: `istream_iterator` reads formatted input (i.e. it skips spaces). you probably want `std::istreambuf_iterator` instead.

Comment: That was it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is behaviour of istream. You can get other behaviour using

- [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline)
- using [`std::streambuf_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istreambuf_iterator)
- using the `stream >>` [`std::noskipws`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/skipws) manipulator (which ends up calling `stream.unsetf(std::ios::skipws)` under the hood)